# Returning char* form C++ function

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have a simple question but unfortunately I wasn't able to find the answear online.

```
const char* foo() const { return "foo"; }
```

Is this 100% safe ?

Comment: Define "100% safe".

Comment: no memory leaks, memory violation, ub

basicly I wouldn't do:
Foo* fooFunction(){
 Foo foo{};
 return &foo;
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is perfectly acceptable from the language PoV.

There's no memory leak of any kind because there are no allocations. The only value constructed is the resulting pointer of primitive type, initialized to point at the literal's location. The pointer returned by this function points to a valid location that can be read and used.

In fact, this function could be marked `constexpr`, as the result can be determined at compile-time, and any program using it will work just as if it used the literal directly.

Comment: This is correct, however we still need the definition of "*100% correct*". I can't find the question right now, but there was a question here that asked about using `const char*` as keys in the map. The question asked about accessing the map values simply with `const char*` and asked whether it was always safe. **It is not**.

Comment: @Fureeish Using `const char*` has nothing to do with returning it from a function, IMHO. That's a topic for, as you've noted, a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "100%". The expression is correct, but keep in mind that the caller is going to need to know the length of the array the returned pointer points to. Either the function returns this value with some parameter or the caller checks the length, but in this case the function must guarantee that the array is NULL terminated.

Comment: String literals are guaranteed to be ended with `'\0'`. For example, given `auto foo = "abc"`, the type of `foo` is `const char[4]`

Comment: The points you make, while valid, don't make much sense in this context. String literals always end with a null character, and string processing functions operating on c-strings never take the length, instead establishing it directly (or sometimes they just don't need it).

Comment: I know, but the caller of the function doesn't necessarily know this, all it sees is a pointer to memory

Comment: have you heard about `strlen()`?

Comment: Yes, and as far as I know if you provide it and array that is not NULL terminated, you'll get a segfault.

Comment: @JorgeJuanTorresQuiroga Pretty much everyone knows what to do with `const char*`. Consider e.g. `std::cout` `operator<<` overload. And speculating about what would this code do if it was different; well if it was different, it would behave differently. As is, it's fine.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking in terms of plain C, nevermind and thanks for the hint!